# debugging: The application does not display

Tags: c#, debugging, datagrid, screen, taskbar

I just debugged my latest application, which reads content of txt files and shows them in a DataGrid. Unfortunately, if I debug my script, it is just shown in the Windows Taskbar with the preview of the application, but it does not display on screen. I cannot see it. Can you tell me why?

It is the only application. All my other applications work well.

**EDIT: I use own settings for displaying my window. The window position was set to -32000 and -32000. That was my fault. Thank you!**

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: is there any `loop` which you use to read content from `txt` file ? Post you code here for better understanding.

Comment: Is your App running? or it were paused in some breakpoint? Your App needs to be running, otherwise it will not be rendered in screen properly.

Comment: Your reading is probably causing an infinite loop.  Please post the code for your reading of a file.

Comment: The code is posted. There is no breakpoint. If you need more code, do not hesitate to tell me. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set your forms `WindowsState` to `Minimized` , maybe ?
If so change it back to `Normal` and it will show up.

Comment: Haha, I do not work with that, but I work with own settings for displaying my window. It is embarrassing. Thanks for your post, it helped to find the solution! ;-)